# How to combine multiple images into a single image with images images height and width controls

Tags: javascript, html

Actually, I am designing a saree by selecting a saree body-color, border color, and border design(all are images). These are multiple images that I am selecting but want to show the designed saree as a single image instead of showing as multiple images.

Already tried that to combine the multiple images as a single image but it couldn't get.

Cannot show you the file because already it has a huge code of HTML, javascript for designing a saree.

Simply want to show the designed saree as a single image instead of multiple images.
Below was the example link:

https://originalstitch.com/design-dress-shirt

In this, the shirts are designing but I want to design a saree. Instead of a shirt, the saree should display with colors, border designs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas

This would allow you to turn your html in a canvas

Then use javascript `canvas.toDataURL('png')`

giving you a base64 string which is a single image

Comment: Also tried the canvas but for that, there are no controllers for the images for adjusting the width and height of the images.

Comment: Using canvas is working but when I am trying to add canvas with a script in the laravel project the images are not displaying. When the page is refreshing the images are simply blink once that's it.

Comment: When I am trying to add the below code in laravel project, the images are not displaying.

Comment: <canvas id="canvas" width="484" height="984"></canvas>